No connection adapters were found for URL
I am doing a API call using Python to Tableau server to get the list of custom Views, bet getting the following error message, No connection adapters were found for {url}
The code snippet is as follows.
str_curl =  "https://URL/api/3.21/sites/0c12f244-f9f8-4de9-8904-3cae238e540c/customviews/1e5c7ccc-2815-4a0d-8158-b6c09326baad" -H " X-Tableau-Auth: pMLm-BY4SQaHE4hK7Y1EAw|bFIKHGa2fyv1GC4ODVCZDo3aQAMlPo4I|0c12f244-f9f8-4de9-8904-3cae238e540c"

result = requests.get( str_curl)

Please let me know if you need more information.

Your URL doesn't really look like a URL you may need to remove spaces. Similar issue here
